# Pass parameter to modal window in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm using the code below to open a modal window (modal_top10), and now I need to pass a parameter ($manager) to this modal. How do I pass this parameter? Via URL?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModaltop10" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <script>
       function top10(){
          $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url:'index.php?r=/client/base/modal_top10',
              success: function(data)
                       {
                           $('#myModaltop10').html(data);
                           $('#myModaltop10').modal();
                       }
          });
       }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not follow the posts. I did the following:

```
<?php
    Modal::begin([
    'header' => "<h4>Top 10</h4>",
    'id' => 'top10',
    'size' => 'model-lg',
    'toggleButton' => [
        'tag' => 'a', 
        'label' => '
        <span style="cursor: pointer;">
            Veja os associados TOP 10 e cadastre sua visita!
            </span>', 
        ]
    ]);
    echo $this->render('_modaltop10', ['manager' => $manager]);
    Modal::end();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

first create _modelview file in view folder with following code. Let url of this page is http://example.com/model/show

```
<?php
     echo $data;
?>
```

note: you must render using  renderAjax() method for this view file in controller model

```
public function actionShow($data)
{
    return $this->renderAjax('_modelview', [
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

You can render view file in model Where you want as

```
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h4>Events</h4>',
    'id' => 'events',
    'size' => 'model-lg',
]);
echo "<div id='modelContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
```

then you can create jquery file to show data in model

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var eventUrl = "http://example.com/model/show";
var data = "data to be sent in this view url for your case $manager";
$.get(eventUrl, {'data': data}, function(data){
    $('#events').modal('show')
    .find('#modelContent')
    .html(data);
});
```

Comment: No work man. 
the modal open ok, but the var $data don't show

Comment: if model open means data is coming from url so use alert(data) before    $('#events').modal('show')
    .find('#modelContent')
    .html(data); and see response

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this without Ajax.

```
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Hello world</h2>',
     'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'click me'],
]);

 echo $manager;

Modal::end();
```

Or, for example, use a bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com/).

In controller:

```
public function actionModalContent(){
   $maanager = /*...*/
   return $this->asJson($this->renderAjax('modal_content_view', ['manager'=>$manager]));
}
```